# jQuery sortable add extra info

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a `li` list that I have made sortable through jQuery. I need to add a few hidden values to this serialized data to make sure the update is going to the right place.

How would I do this?

**HTML**

```
<ul id="reportNav">
  <li id=page_1>Page 1</li>
  <li id=page_2>Page 2</li>
  <li id=page_3>Page 3</li>
  <li id=page_4>Page 4</li>
  <li id=page_5>Page 5</li>
  <li id=page_6>Page 6</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$("#reportNav").sortable({
    stop : function(event, ui){
    var url = "/pages/saveOrder.php";
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: url,
         data: $(this).sortable('serialize');,
         success: function(data) { alert(data); },
         error: function(data) { alert("Failure"); }
       });
     }
});
```

**Outputted Data:** `page[]=1&page[]=2&page[]=3&page[]=4&page[]=5&page[]=6`

**Data I need to add:** Specific `reportID` that is in the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just add it `$(this).sortable('serialize')+"&reportId="+$("#reportId").text()` http://jsfiddle.net/8BAW3/

---

Or give an example of what do you want to achieve if it isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

This is old but if anyone looking at this need to add more data you probably change the data attribute to something like:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     data: {
         data: $(this).sortable('serialize'),
         foo: 'bar',
         bar: 'blubb'
     },
     success: function(data) { alert(data); },
     error: function(data) { alert("Failure"); }
   });
```

Do a `var_dump($_POST)` to wherever you are submitting the ajax request to see/find the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can just append a parameter to the data part as a text (*+'&param=value'*). The string can be changed for your variable as well.

```
        $.ajax({
            data: data+'&param=value',
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/yourFile.php'
        });
```